# Why doesn't ConfigureAwait(false) prevent deadlock if it's inside an iteration?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, async-await, task

Can someone please explain why `AsyncMethod2` causes a deadlock? I (think I) understand that the top level Task in `AsyncMethod1` doesn't try to execute it's continuation on the context which is captured by `BlockingMethod`, hence avoiding a deadlock, but I don't understand what's going on under the hood in `AsyncMethod2`:

```
private static void BlockingMethod(IEnumerable<Object> data)
{
    AsyncMethod1(data).Wait();  // no deadlock
    AsyncMethod2(data).Wait();  // deadlock
}

private static async Task AsyncMethod1(IEnumerable<Object> data)
{
    await Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        foreach (var obj in data)
        {
            await AsyncMethod2.(obj);
        }
    }).ConfigureAwait(false);
}

private static async Task AsyncMethod2(IEnumerable<Object> data)
{
    await Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        foreach (var obj in data)
        {
            await AsyncMethod2.(obj).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `await` in `AsyncMethod2` is returning to its context. I'm referring to the `await` that is actually in `AsyncMethod2` - that is, the `await Task.Run(...);`. There's no `ConfigureAwait(false)` for that `await`, so it will resume to its context.

Whether there's a `ConfigureAwait(false)` within the loop or not is immaterial, because that loop runs on a thread pool thread (`Task.Run`) where there is no context anyway.

Comment: Thanks a lot :) I want to make sure I get it - when the await of `await Task.Run(...)` returns to it's context - there's where the deadlock takes place, right? Because that context is captured by `BlockingMethod(...)`. Is that correct?

Comment: @shay__: The context is captured by `AsyncMethod2`. More precisely, it's captured by the `await Task.Run(...)` statement. Remember that `await Task.Run(...);` is essentially the same as `var runTask = Task.Run(...); await runTask;` and the context is captured immediately before `await runTask;` and used to resume the method immediately after `await runTask;`.

Comment: So now I'm even more confused, lol. `await Task.Run(...)` captures the context - who is the second Task that tries to resume to that context?

Comment: @shay__: The `async` method (`AsyncMethod2`) resumes on the context. There's no "second task". You may find my [async intro](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) helpful.

Comment: Oh I did, many times! I just don't understand which is the second "competitor" (`AsyncMethod2` is one) that causes the deadlock in this case.

Comment: @shay__: I explain this kind of deadlock in my [don't block on async code](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) blog post. You have two things waiting for each other: one is the call to `Task.Wait` within `BlockingMethod`; the other is the task returned from `AsyncMethod2`. The task is waiting for the context to be free, and the thread is blocked (holding that context) waiting for the task to complete.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comprehensive answers. I find myself going back to your articles every now and then - they do a great service online :)